# How to set radiobuttonlist based on text

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery ui and I've got a radiobuttonlist that renders like so:

```
     <span id="MainContent_rblModule" title="Select what module this issue pertains to.">
<input id="MainContent_rblModule_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblModule" value="11" /><label for="MainContent_rblModule_0">Meeting</label>
<input id="MainContent_rblModule_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblModule" value="10" /><label for="MainContent_rblModule_1">Service Order</label>
<input id="MainContent_rblModule_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblModule" value="6" checked="checked" /><label for="MainContent_rblModule_2">Sub Project</label>
<input id="MainContent_rblModule_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblModule" value="6" /><label for="MainContent_rblModule_3">IT</label><br />
<input id="MainContent_rblModule_4" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblModule" value="6" /><label for="MainContent_rblModule_4">Engineering Services</label>
<input id="MainContent_rblModule_5" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblModule" value="6" /><label for="MainContent_rblModule_5">Building Maintenance</label>
<input id="MainContent_rblModule_6" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblModule" value="6" /><label for="MainContent_rblModule_6">Ask The CEO</label>
<input id="MainContent_rblModule_7" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblModule" value="6" /><label for="MainContent_rblModule_7">Safety</label><br /></span>
```

If I wanted to select the radio button list by value I could easily do:

```
var radio = $("[id*=MainContent_rblModule] input[value=" + projectId + "]");
radio.prop("checked", true).button("refresh");
```

But I need to select based on text so I tried:

```
var text = "IT";
var radio = $("[id*=MainContent_rblModule] label:contains('" + text + "')").find("input");
 radio.prop("checked", true).button("refresh");
```

This doesn't work...but I tried to figure out the best way to do this, maybe contains is not a good idea...

Comment: `("[id*=MainContent_rblModule] label ......` This is wrong. since input tag is a void element. :\  `#MainContent_rblModule` will be enough to grab that span

Comment: So whats the end result here...I tried removing that as well with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
var text = "IT";
var radios = $("#MainContent_rblModule label:contains('" + text + "')");
radios.each(function(){
 $(this).prev('input').prop("checked", true).button("refresh");
});
```